# Fancybox opens direct link instead of window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to create a fancybox that opens an iframe window. The window will hold an article created in HTML and placed in same folder as main page. For some reason I can't get it to work. Instead of opening a window, it opens in a new tab. Please let me know if you need more info and thanks for any help! My code is below:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webfont/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 749px)" href="main-phone.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1099px)" href="main-thin.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="main-wide.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 960,
    maxHeight   : 540,
    minWidth    : 480,
    minHeight   : 320,
    fitToView   : false,
    width   : '80%',
    height  : '80%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'none'
    });
    });
    </script>       

    </head>
    <body id="index">

    <div id="container">

    <!-- START ROW 1 -->
    <div id="wrap1">
    <div id="wrapa">

    <div class="box1">
    <h2>Article stuff</h2>
    <a href="test.html" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" title="article 1">READ ARTICLE</a>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
    <h2>Lore ipsum</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
    <h2>Lore ipsum</h2>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END ROW 1 -->`
```

Comment: all the API options and special classes (like `fancybox.iframe`) that you are using are for fancybox v2.x but you seem to be loading fancybox v1.3.4. Options for those versions are different and not compatible with each other. For how-to use v1.3.4 check http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! With much help from the online community I was able to piece together a working fancybox.